# Jboss JMS Out Of Memory

Tags: jboss, jms

I am using JBOSS 5.1. And we are using JMS(topic) for posting the messages and JMS client will take those messages, to be specific i am using durable subscription.
It works on many systems, but on one system i always see this error after two days.

```
2012-08-30 12:59:27,045 WARNING [sun.rmi.transport.tcp] (RMI TCP Accept-1101) RMI TCP Accept-11101: accept loop for ServerSocket[addr=/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=11101] throws
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:597)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addIfUnderMaximumPoolSize
```

Not sure why it is occuring only to one system, and only one JMS client is connected to Jboss for listening messages.

Answer (score 2):

You should mention the details of your system, in particular the OS you are running and the Java startup parameters included in your jboss start script.
Chances are that you are running out of thread resources/file descriptors or you have set a thread stack which is not sufficient.
[See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221273/jboss-jms-out-of-memory)
Hope it helps

Comment: your link "see this thread" ; link the current page - i don't think this will help ;)

Comment: right link is pointing to my post only, i am using WiN2k8 R2.